# how to clear FlatList in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a "products" useState that stores a list of products, I then display them using FlatList

Here is the products code

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
```

And here is the FlatList

```
    <FlatList data={products} renderItem={(productData) => {
      try {
        console.log(products);
        return <ProductCard 
          image={productData.item.image}
          title={productData.item.title}
          rating={productData.item.rating}
          ratings_total={productData.item.ratings_total}
          price={productData.item.price.value}
          symbol={productData.item.price.symbol}
        />
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }}/>
```

When I change the products list, so it doesn't contain any old data, the FlatList still displays the old data, and displays the new data under it.

How can I clear the FlatList before displaying the new data so the old data isn't displayed anymore?

Comment: How do you try to clear the FlatList? `setProducts([])`?

Comment: No that just changes the list, so when I set the products to new products, it kind of does what you said, but the FlatList still displays the old products that's the problem

Comment: My question was, how (and where) in your code do you clear the products? To clear it I assumed you call `setProducts([])` but obviously this may be different if you implemented it differently. Currently your question is missing this (likely important) information

Comment: oh I did not do that, thanks that solved it